# Can I animate visual attributes for multiple objects simultaneously in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I’m trying to show a D3 hive plot animation representing internet attack data over time using d3.hive.min.js. The base view has 2 axes. Along one axis is a set of source IP addresses – the IP address from which the attack originated. The other axis shows destination IP addresses. 
A static view showing the set of attacks (each involving one source and one destination IP) looks like this:
[Hive Plot Source/Destination Network Paths - Static View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU5e8.png)

*Each attack has a start time and an end time, which provides a temporal sequencing*.
The desired visualization will cause the links to appear and disappear in temporal order, preferably with a variable duration computed from the start/end times. However, a constant time for the appearance of each link would suffice.
I’m using d3.hive.min.js to create the plot axes and links. 
I’ve tried a number of approaches without success:

- Creating all links with opactity 0, then cycling through a set of
  “time steps” where I reset the opactity of each link based on it’s
  state at that time. This has the advantage of having ultimate control
  of the opacity values based on computations based on start and end
  time. I've tried variations with and without transitions and delays.
- Bringing the links in one at a time. The result is not the exact
  desired result, as it would show build-up of links over time, rather
  than them coming and disappearing over time.
- Creating and removing the links as they occur over time. With this
  approach I don’t understand how I would be able to show overlapping attack
  events, where multiple links should appear at same time.

My question at this point is foremost “is this possible with D3”? I'm no expert with D3, but have spent well over 10 hours experimenting and searching. I would very much appreciate a suggestion of an approach with which I could experiment, or a pointer to a similar example.

Comment: Yes, this is possible -- in particular it sounds like your first approach should work fine. How does it not?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff After code that successfully draws the hive plot axes, nodes, and links I've tried e.g.the following:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j< links.length; j++) {
    d3.selectAll(".link")
    .style("opacity", i/10)
    }  
  }    All I see is the final opacity. I assume either it is drawing too fast to see intermediate opacities, or D3 is skipping to a final state. I don't known if I can work with transitions; or some inserted delay; or if just on the wrong track. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You're just looping and not transitioning. Try something like `d3.selectAll(".link").transition().style("opacity", 1)`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I now have this code using .transition with intent to reset the opacities in steps (based on opacities array). The result I see is the final state only. I have put the code at [grhiveplot](https://github.com/grrogers/hiveplotanimation/tree/master). Here is the loop in which I'm attempting to reset opacity:
for (var j = 0; j< opacities.length; j++) {
  links[0].opacity = opacities[j][0];
  links[1].opacity = opacities[j][1];

  d3.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .transition()
    // tried duration & delay
    .style("opacity", function (d) {return d.opacity;})
  }

Comment: You don't need a loop, just a single transition.

Comment: In final display I will have several thousand links covering several months. I want the display to be a time animation. As I step through the links in time order I want to make the link appear, and stay for some period of time based on accompanying data. So I need more than a single transition. I need a transition for each time step it seems. Links will appear and disappear over a period of perhaps a minute or more while the animation runs. At any time only a few or perhaps 10-25 of thousands of links will be present. Perhaps I'm trying to do something not suitable for D3?

Comment: You can chain transitions with `.transition().attr(...).transition().attr(...)`.